# Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

While I am running android studio, the warning below appears:

> Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>   In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages

How can I resolve this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

CommonsWare answer is correct. Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

If you are using gradle dependency try excluding org.json from the package.

```
compile ('com.your.dependency.name:0.0.0'){
  exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

This one worked for me.

Comment: To understand which one has the org.json dependency, you can search for application depoendencies using `gradlew app:dependencies` on terminal in android studio.

Answer (score 4):

It would appear to be that you are trying to use some Java dependency that is not set up for Android. Most likely, it is whatever dependency you just added. That could be for `org.json:json`, or it could be for something else that has a transitive dependency on `org.json:json`.

If you added the dependency on `org.json:json` yourself, just use the copy of those classes that are in the Android SDK.

If you added a dependency on something else, and it is what is requiring `org.json:json`, talk to the developers of the library you are trying to use and discuss with them how best to use that library on Android.

Comment: thank you for reply,i am using dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:engine.io-client:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1'
}

Comment: @sky: Well, it is not coming from `appcompat-v7` or a bare JAR, so the `org.json:json` dependency is coming from one of the other three libraries. Note that there are Android-ready WebSocket and socket.io libraries, [like AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync).