# Gradle Build warning on org.json dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, dependencies, compiler-warnings

I've added `compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'` in `build.gradle` file for using updated version `JSON`. but, I got warnings with message saying

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

how to resolve this?

I want to `exclude` `org.json:json` from `android.jar` file.

keep the `compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'`. how to do that.

[image]

I've tried adding

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude 'org/json/**'
            }
        }
    }
```

but, didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Ka7Im1011, did you saw these links? https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client-java/issues/13 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921328/dependency-org-jsonjson20090211-is-ignored-for-debug-as-it-may-be-conflicting

Comment: Hi @Jaco I've seen your link  but, that is not my case. I want to `exclude` `org.json:json` from `Android.jar` file. how to do that.

Comment: The only way I was able to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60196396/1438339