# How to resolve Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20080701 is ignored for release?

Tags: android, json

This warning appears when I enable **`minifyEnabled true`**.

I already tried `exclude group: 'org.json'`

But did not get succeeded. How to omit this warning for release APK.

> Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20080701 is ignored for release as it
>   may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Below is my Dependency .

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.thebluealliance:spectrum:0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    compile project(':colorpicker')
    //Add the following lines one is for firebase and one is for volley
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: did you used external json dependency in project?

Comment: i think compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4 is not needed. GSON is available already. and use same version for support library.

Comment: No issue with  `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4` . Removed gson from dependencies and clean project. Still, the issue is same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33142572/6756514

Comment: try this compile('ch.acra:acra:4.5.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.json'
}

Comment: Ok Trying. Let you know.

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Hey Thanks Solved issue by your code `compile('ch.acra:acra:4.5.0') { exclude group: 'org.json' } `. Actually I was missguided by logcat because it showing me error in `colorpicker` library.